# How to create SSLStream which uses Ssl3 instead of Tls

Tags: c#, ssl, tcpclient, sslstream

I'm trying to establish tcp connection which is encrypted using Ssl3.

Basically I'm just creating TCP connection and than I'm creating SSLStream on top of that:

```
var ss = new SslStream(poolItem.SecureConnection, false, remoteCertificateValidationCallback);

ss.ReadTimeout = ss.WriteTimeout = timeout;

ss.AuthenticateAsClient(host);

var pp = ss.SslProtocol;
```

My problem is that by default SslStream uses TLS. I want for it to be Ssl3.

In HttpWebRequest, you can use following code to change the protocol:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

I checked it, and it doesn't affect SslStream.

How do I change SslStream's protocol to Ssl3?

Comment: Perhaps you could start by using the `AuthenticateAsClient` overload that allows you to specify the enabled SSL protocols?

Comment: hehe. yeah. I just went through the code and found that myself ((. just post that as an answer and I'll award it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use the `AuthenticateAsClient` overload that lets you specify which protocols should be allowed:

```
AuthenticateAsClient
  (host, new X509CertificateCollection(), SslProtocols.Ssl3, false);
```